# is there a way to plot multiple lines using hvplot.line from an xarray array

Tags: line, python-xarray, hvplot

I have multiple ytraces data in an xarray array.
data trace selection can be done by

```
t=s_xr_all.sel(trace_index=slice(0,2,1),xy='y') 
# trace_index and xy are dimension names and above selects subset of 3 traces (lines) into t
t.name='t'
t.hvplot.line(x='point_index',y='t')
```

The above creates a line plot with a widget slider that allows scrolling through the lines with single line displayed at a time
I would like to be able to plot all lines without creating the slider widget.hvplot documentation is sparse as to how to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
t.hvplot.line(x='point_index',y='t').overlay()
```

The .overlay() function chaining eliminates the slider creation and all the lines in the xarray are displayed